# Error: [matroska,webm @ XXXXX ] max_analyze_duration reached

Tags: 14.04, avconv

I am using this command to transcode from my DVB recordings to H.264:

```
avconv -i "$1" -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy "$1".mkv >> "$1".log 2>&1
```

`$1` is the file.

These are my first lines of log output:

```
avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[matroska,webm @ 0x8689e0] Unknown/unsupported AVCodecID S_DVBSUB.
[matroska,webm @ 0x8689e0] max_analyze_duration reached**
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'file.mkv':
Metadata: [... some text ...]
 Duration: 04:01:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0.0(ger): Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 720x576 [PAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 15000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
  Stream #0.1(ger): Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s (default)
  Stream #0.2(ger): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 384 kb/s (default)
  Stream #0.3(ger): Subtitle: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000 (default)
```

I am wondering about the `max_analyze_duration reached` error. What can I do about it? If I search the web for it, I find a lot, but not much about video encoding.